# I have 2 Scripts that need to be combined

Tags: google-apps-script

I apologize for my ignorance but would greatly appreciate any assistance that could be provided. I am far from knowing what I am doing when it comes to writing. I generally just use what I find that is already written and alter it to fit my needs.

Script 1: looks in cell B3 on “CopyFromWB” to see if employee # already exists in a separate WB “PasteToWB”. If employee number already exists it returns the row # that the employee # appears on.

I want to have Script 2 to contain an “If”, so that if the the employee # exists it does not add this same employee again in lastrow() but uses the row number “3” produced by Script 1

Skips the following two steps:

```
destinationSS.getRange(destinationSS.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, 4).setValues(sourceVals);
destinationSS.getRange(destinationSS.getLastRow(), 5).setValue(new Date());
```

and adds the “In Training” to Row 3 columns 10 & 11:

```
destinationSS.getRange(**3**, 10).setValue("In Training");
destinationSS.getRange(**3**, 11).setValue("In Training");
```

**Script 1**

```
function searcher() {
const searchString = SpreadsheetApp.openById("CopyFromWb").getSheetByName("CopyFromSheet").getRange(3,2).getValue();
const sheetSrch = SpreadsheetApp.openById("PasteToWb").getSheetByName("PasteToSheet");
const srchCol = 1;
const srchRng = sheetSrch.getRange(2,srchCol,sheetSrch.getLastRow());
const srchData = srchRng.getValues();
Logger.log(srchData);
const result = srchData.finder(searchString);
console.log(result);
 
}
 
Array.prototype.finder = function(val){
if(val == "") return false;
const arr = [];
for(let i=0;i<this.length;i++){
if(this[i].toString().indexOf(val) > -1){
arr.push(i);
}
}
return arr[0];
}
```

Execution log
12:59:22 Execution started
12:59:23 PM​Info​[[Employee #], [123455.0], [180211.0], [123454.0], [180212.0], [123456.0], [123457.0], [123454.0], [123454.0], [123454.0], [123454.0], [123454.0], [123454.0], [123454.0], [123454.0], []]

12:59:23 PM​Info​3
12:59:24 Execution completed

**Script 2**

```
function IDName() {
ImportRange(
" CopyFromWb",
" CopyFromSheet!B3:E3",
" PasteToWb",
);
}
 
function ImportRange(sourceID, sourceRange,destinationID) {
 
const sourceSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceID);
const sourceRng = sourceSS.getRange(sourceRange);
const sourceVals = sourceRng.getValues();
const destinationSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(destinationID).getSheetByName("PasteToSheet");
//const destRange = destinationSS.getRange(destinationSS.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, 4);
 
destinationSS.getRange(destinationSS.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, 4).setValues(sourceVals);
destinationSS.getRange(destinationSS.getLastRow(), 5).setValue(new Date());
destinationSS.getRange(destinationSS.getLastRow(), 10).setValue("In Training");
destinationSS.getRange(destinationSS.getLastRow(), 11).setValue("In Training");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to test this but I'm pretty sure it will work for you.

The Array.prototype.finder is not needed because there is already a native method Array.findIndex().

Also your last lines of script 2 are confusing.  It is supposed to fill in the new row or update the row just above the new row.

Code.gs

```
function searcher() {
  try {
    const searchString = SpreadsheetApp.openById("CopyFromWb").getSheetByName("CopyFromSheet").getRange(3,2).getValue();
    const sheetSrch = SpreadsheetApp.openById("PasteToWb").getSheetByName("PasteToSheet");
    const srchCol = 1;
    const srchRng = sheetSrch.getRange(2,srchCol,sheetSrch.getLastRow()-1); // -1 since you start at row 2
    const srchData = srchRng.getValues();
    console.log(srchData);
    const result = srchData.findIndex( row => row[0] === searchString );
    console.log(result);
    return result;
  }
  catch(err) {
   throw "\nError in searcher: "+err;
  }
}

function ImportRange(sourceID, sourceRange,destinationID) {
  try {
    const sourceSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceID);
    const sourceRng = sourceSS.getRange(sourceRange);
    const sourceVals = sourceRng.getValues();
    const destinationSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(destinationID).getSheetByName("PasteToSheet");
    //const destRange = destinationSS.getRange(destinationSS.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, 4);

    let index = searcher();
    index = index < 0 ? destinationSS.getLastRow()+1 : index+2;
    destinationSS.getRange(index, 1, 1, 4).setValues(sourceVals);
    // not sure if these are supposed to be last row or new row?
    destinationSS.getRange(index, 5).setValue(new Date());
    destinationSS.getRange(index, 10).setValue("In Training");
    destinationSS.getRange(index, 11).setValue("In Training");
  }
  catch(err) {
    throw "\nError in ImportRange: "+err;
  }
}
```

Reference

- [Array.findIndex()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_findindex.asp)

Comment: The if the employee ID # exists in the PasteToSheet then the last 2 rows containing setValue(“In Training”) are the only 2 changes that will be made and they will be made to the row value derived from the Finder Script 1. If the employee ID # does not exists in the PasteToSheet then the whole Script 2 should operate as it is currently laid out.  The first 2 lines: 1).“destinationSS.getRange(index, 1, 1, 4).setValues(sourceVals);”        2). “destinationSS.getRange(index, 5).setValue(new Date());”                   1. Paste the Range from CopyfromSheet that contains ID, name, etc. and 2. Date.

Comment: does that make more sense?

Comment: That is what I have coded.  Make a copy of your spreadsheet, insert this script and try it.

Comment: The Execution Log showed complete and the correct row was identified. However, no changes were made to the “PasteToSheet”.

Comment: I removed all data in the “PasteToSheet” which would cause the function Searcher() to give a value of -1. In this case the function ImportRange() should take the 1 row 4 column(cell) range from the “CopyFromSheet” and paste ghem into the last row of the “PasteToSheet”. Again there was no changes/activity on the “PasteToSheet”.

Comment: Clearly if index is not -1 but some number 0 or greater than those rows should be changed in your `destinationSS`.  Row 2 would be index 0 from `searcher()`.

Comment: I get that but, Something isn’t coming through properly because it is not setting (setvalues) any values in DestinationSS

Comment: Without your data files there is no way for me to tell.  You have all the try{} catch(){} blocks in your code?